# Is it possible to create a Rust function that inputs and outputs an edited value, without killing its' lifetime?

Tags: rust, reference, mutable

I need a function that should accept a vector without killing its' lifetime, but still being able to get modified (so no reference).

The modification in this case is the following: You have a vector of a certain structure, that has a `children` attribute which is a vector of this same type. The function takes the last struct of the vector, gets into it's children, once again gets the last of the children's vector, gets once again into the children, and so n times. Then the function returns the n-th level child.

How would I go about making a compilable code like following pseudo code?

```rust
fn g(vector: Vec<...>, n: numeric input) {
   let temporary;
   n times {
      temporary = vector.last().unwrap().children;
   }
   return temporary;
}

let vec = Vec // Existing Vector
g(vec).push() // pushes into a certain child element of the vec element, this child is received over the function.
```

However the above thing won't work since by giving the vector to the function, it's ownership is granted to the function and it's lifetime expires here.

Comment: Just to make it clear what the actual question is: you'd like to write a function with the signature like `insert()` (but presumably taking `&mut Vec<Token>`), where the code you've shown is your attempt at getting there which doesn't compile? Alternatively you're open to different solutions that would achieve the same goal.

Comment: Precisely. I was coding JavaScript for long and a language without a garbage collector but lifetimes is a very new concept. I at first even hesitated what I actually am looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

<s>(This is all very difficult to do correctly without an [M.R.E.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or even a copypaste of your compiler-errors - thus I'll proceed via theoretical analysis and educated guessing.)</s>

Even though you pass in the tokens via `&mut`, that gets automagically converted into a nonexclusive `&` reference because that's what's in the signature. You can't then get an exclusive reference from that, only a mutable name that holds nonexclusive references.

You need an exclusive reference in order to do that `push` operation - the "many readers XOR one writer" principle requires that.

Once you have `outermost_vector` as an exclusive reference, you then need to assign more exclusive references to it. `last` returns nonexclusive references, so that's out. But since `outermost_vector` is now an exclusive reference, you can call [`slice::last_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.last_mut) on it. Then - assuming all of this is even possible in the first place - you just need to [follow the compiler-errors](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-02-multithreaded.html#improving-throughput-with-a-thread-pool) to fix up other minor things such as the intricacies of correctly pattern-matching the intermediate values.

You also need to fix the function's overall typing; `Vec::push` returns `()`, which thankfully is not a member of the type `Vec<Token>`.

And as to the title of your question: since you're taking an `&'a mut Vec<Token>`, if you want to return some data borrowed from that then you should type your return as `&'a mut Vec<Token>`, not `Vec<Token>` over which your function has no ownership.

(Question was edited significantly, new answer follows:)

Your function must accept `vector` not by value, but by exclusive reference (spelled `&mut` rather than `&`). Then you can return another exclusive reference, one which is borrowed from the exclusive reference that was passed-in, but points directly to the desired receiver of `push`. The function's type signature would be something like `fn g(vector: &mut Vec<T>, n: usize) -> &mut Vec<T>`.

Passing by value would cause the function to take ownership of the whole thing - all owned data not returned are dropped, and this is probably not what you want.

Passing by nonexclusive reference is not what you want either, since there is no way to then convert that back to an exclusive reference with which to call `push` - even if you're back at the callsite where you have ownership of the data from which the reference is borrowed-from.

Comment: Hi, I edited the question to be more abstract and on-point, I hope this might be a step forward.

Comment: And I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: so i can without any problems provide a mutable reference in the structure given? There was probably confusion from my side around whether ownership will move or not. Thank you.

Comment: No, mutable referencing doesn't move ownership, that's the point of mutable references.

Comment: For most functions, `f(x: T) -> T` is a more limited form of `fn(x: &mut T)`.

Comment: strangely, i could only borrow one mutable reference in my code, maybe I am misunderstanding something?

Comment: I think a new SO question containing an MRE of what you've just described, would be far more useful to you than this current question.

Comment: There's a problem with SO, that you can't ask many questions. You have to fight your problem in the same question until you get an answer, or you're doomed to be only allowed to ask five questions like every year.